# Prolog - execute from command line, load multiple files, execute query, exit

Tags: command-line, prolog

I want to run a prolog file (`Load.pl`) from a Windows command line, executing a query (that outputs its result to a file) and exit.

My `Load.pl` file loads multiple source files:

```
/**
Loading files
*/
consult('C:/MyPath/Prolog/Segments_5.pl').
consult('C:/MyPath/Prolog/Segments_Global.pl').
consult('C:/MyPath/Prolog/Produits.pl').
consult('C:/MyPath/Prolog/SelChemin.pl').
consult('C:/MyPath/Prolog/OutputFunctions.pl').
```

The command line I'm ucrrently using is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\swipl\bin\swipl.exe" -f 'C:/MyPath/Prolog/Load.pl' -g output_src('test.txt'),halt -t 'halt(1)'
```

The query I want to run is in this case `output_src('test.txt')`

Its implementation is in the `OutputFunctions.pl` file:

```
output_src(Path) :-
    open(Path, write, Stream),
    (   propose_source(ListeSources), write(Stream, ListeSources), fail
    ;   true
    ),
    close(Stream).
```

When I open the prolog terminal, and manually execute the 5 `consult` instruction and then the `output_src` instruction it works fine, but when it is executed by the command line, I get an error message telling me this:

```
ERROR: Prolog initialisation failed:
ERROR: '<meta-call>'/1: Undefined procedure: output_src2/0
```

P.S.: I'm really just starting with prolog and I need to interface it with some .NET code.

Thanks for any help provided !
Regards,
Joël

Comment: `load.pl` does not actually **load** anything. You are only defining Prolog facts of the form `consult(...).`. To actually load a file, either use a directive like `:- include(File).`, or `:- use_module(Module).`, **or** invoke SWI-Prolog with multiple files as arguments, such as: `$ swipl file1.pl file2.pl file3.pl etc.`.

Answer (score 2):

Have a close look at the error message:

```
ERROR: Prolog initialisation failed:
ERROR: ''/1: Undefined procedure: output_src2/0
```

Note that it does not find `output_src2/0`, i.e., the predicate with arity **zero**.

Why is it looking for `output_src2` with arity zero?

Probably because the command line flag:

```
-g output_src('test.txt'),halt
```

should rather read:

```
-g "output_src('test.txt'),halt"
```

or:

```
-g 'output_src(\'test.txt\'),halt'
```

The exact quoting rules depend on your shell and OS.

Comment: thanks, I tried to simplify for better understanding: , I used `output_src2` method withoud parameter, and tried to call it as you said with `-g output_src2,halt` or `-g "output_src2,halt"` which produce the same result (`ERROR: Prolog initialisation failed:
ERROR: '<meta-call>'/1: Undefined procedure: output_src2/0`). If I call with  `-g 'output_src2,halt'` it produce `ERROR: Prolog initialisation failed:
ERROR: ignore/1: Undefined procedure: 'output_src2,halt'/0`.

Comment: Note: after a few tests, I think the problem comes from the fact that I load a "load.pl" file which only consists in a few `consult` calls. When all the code is in one unique file, it works, but it seems I have a problem when I need to consult several files before being able to call a procedure. Even when I double-click on the `Load.pl` file it doesn't work, but if I open prolog terminal, manually enter the `consult` operations then call `output_src2.` here only it is good. Do you know why ?

Comment: I find the fact that `-g 'output_src2,halt'` yields that error for you quite irritating: In Debian 8.2, I get, when I try: `$ swipl -g 'write(a),write(b),halt'` as expected the output `ab`. You may have found an issue with argument processing on your platform. Please try more tests and then consider filing an issue.

Comment: If I run `swipl -g "write(a),write(b),halt"` (from a Windows dos shell) I get the output `ab` correctly. In fact if I regroup all my pl sources files in one single file (named `regrouped.pl`) and then run `swipl -f regrouped.pl -g output_src2,halt` it works fine. I think there is something not working whith my load.pl file and the `consult` statements.

Comment: I added one more comment to your question: You are currently not loading anything, just defining Prolog facts of the predicate `consult/1`.